# What is setElementConverter and how does it work in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem in finding element where page gets refreshed. Now trying to do anything on the element throws below `StaleElementReferenceException` with a message `Element is no longer valid`

Looking up this [url](https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)

there's a **note** on the above ref url about :

`Should you wish to head down this route, the simplest hook point is to call setElementConverter`

what or how is the `setElementConverter` used ? googled up for a bit and couldn't find an actual implementation of the method mentioned.

Comment: Can you give a code snippet which does not work?

Comment: Same here, cannot find info about `setElementConverter`, even in the doc itself and in the source code. And `setElementConverter` (from class `RemoteWebDriver`) is `protected`, so in their cryptic "Should you wish..." hint they also seem to be implying that their "down this route" involves extending `RemoteWebDriver` and calling `setElementConverter` from somewhere in the subclass.

Comment: @bandeesh-r-sirga In case this is an XY question and you're actually just trying to get things working with Selenium, you need to re-find the element once it's stale. If you get a StaleElementException, driver.findElement(By) again and the element will no longer be stale. Elements go "stale" if the DOM tree changes at that node or above it in the hierarchy. Would finding the element again suit your needs, or do you absolutely have to deal with the same stale element that you originally found?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be heading down the wrong path by focusing on `setElementConverter`. As the [documentation page you linked](https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) suggests, you should simply try to find the element again if it went stale.

> If the element has been replaced with an identical one, a useful strategy is to look up the element again.

I think that if you are a beginner Selenium user, you should follow this advice and stop here. Try-Catch the stale element exception and just find the element again without worrying about `setElementConverter`.

---

If you are looking into more advanced behavior of Selenium or are dead set in satisfying your curiosity into `setElementConverter`, then the following lines will matter more.

> If you do this automatically, be aware that you may well be opening your tests to a race condition and potential flakiness.
>
> ...
>
> Should you wish to head down this route, the simplest hook point is to call setElementConverter.

The documentation is saying that you may **try to write something clever** *in order to automatically repeat the find for the element*, but that causes flakiness and race conditions. I don't think anybody in practice actually tries to overcome StaleElementExceptions this way because it's complicated and flaky, and the easiest solution is to re-find the element in your own code.

As @SantiBailors pointed out in his comment, setElementConverter is a `protected` method in `RemoteWebDriver`.

- [Selenium API Documentation for RemoteWebDriver setElementConverter](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#setElementConverter-org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter-)
- [Selenium source code on GitHub for RemoteWebDriver setElementConverter](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java#L525)

  - [JsonToWebElementConverter Class in the source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter.java)

It looks like you would extend RemoteWebDriver and inject additional behavior into the "hook" of setElementConverter, or provide your own `JsonToWebElementConverter` to change that behavior to automatically retry or deal with the stale element.

How you would do this, I'm not sure. This is where my knowledge ends, and I've never heard of anyone taking this advice to hook into `setElementConverter`. Again, I'd like to reiterate that this probably isn't what you want to be doing, and most likely you just want to find the element again in your own code, which can be done so much more simply by using a try-catch for `StaleElementException` and trying again after some ThreadSleep or [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly access `setElementConverter` method of `RemoteWebDriver` as it is protected. It can be used by extending webdriver.

One of the example of how the `setElementConverter` can be used, is in [QAFExtendedWebDriver](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/blob/b15a00381203cfe1b61d11bdb78ad66f3337897e/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/ui/webdriver/QAFExtendedWebDriver.java#L133) of [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) where QAF has extended webdriver and webelement to have additional features like [listeners](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html), inbuilt [assertion, verification](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/assertion_verification.html), [wait](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/wait_service.html), [self-descriptive locator](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/locating_elements.html#self-descriptive-locator) and so on.